# foreach anchor tag class active in tab

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have razor view where I am hardcoding values like "PROP/GNICS" to show it in Tab. But now I want to make it dynamic.

```
<ul id="businessTab" class="nav nav-tabs tab_nav sub_pcvnav">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#Prop" data-toggle="tab">
            PROP <span class="vbox businessTab_PROP">0.000</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    @if (IsCCSelected)
    {
        <li>
            <a href="#gnics" data-toggle="tab">
                GNICS <span class="vbox businessTab_PROP">0.000</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li class="disabled disable_gnics">
            <span>
                <b> GNICS</b> <span class="vbox businessTab_GNICS">0.000</span>
            </span>
        </li>
    }

</ul>
```

Dynamic Code :

```
 <ul id="businessTab" class="nav nav-tabs tab_nav sub_pcvnav">
    @foreach (var item in Model.LookUp)
    {
        <li>
            <a href=@String.Concat("#",@item.LookUpName) data-toggle="tab">
                @item.LookUpName <span class="vbox businessTab_@item.LookUpName">0.000</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

But here I am not able to set active class in `<Li>`. How to set that ?

```
<li class="active">
```

In foreach loop it will set both class as active ?

Comment: So basically whenever this view loads up first `<li>` element should have an active class. If this is what you need and you are are comfortable with jQuery then why not add `$('#businessTab li:first').addClass('active');` in document ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not get your question clearly. But I think, you want to add some classes dinamically.

Maybe one of these will help you

```
<li class="@(item.LookUpName == "GNICS" ? "disabled disable_gnics" : "")">

<li class="@(IsCCSelected ? "" : "disabled disable_gnics")">
```